# NETLOGO: find all csv files in a directory and read them in

Tags: csv, import, netlogo

I don't know how many CSV files in my directory area. However, I would like to read in all of them and save them in global variables that are numbered consecutively.

In R, it would look something like this:

```
datapath = "D:\\example"
files <- dir(datapath)

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
assign(paste("data",i, sep="_"), read.csv(paste(datapath,files[i], sep="\\"), header=FALSE))
}
```

which gives me several data frames named data_1, data_2, data_3,....

How can I do the same in NETLOGO???  I have my NetLogo model (.nlogo) and my CSV files (.csv) saved in the same folder.

Comment: NetLogo is not really set up for dynamic variable creation, though you might be able to do something with `runresult` or with some of the extensions (R and csv and filepath could all help). But after importing, you would also need all sorts of awkward code to access the variables. Could you please explain further why you need this to be dynamic? For example, is the model going to be run with different sets of csv files regularly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use the R extension.

```
extensions[r]
```

Then you could do what ever you want to do with the csv files in R and then get the data back in netlogo or get a list of csv files (that is what the example below does).

```
r:eval "source(MyFunctionScript.r)"
r:eval "data = getDatafunction()"
let data r:get "data"
```

The r function would look something like:

```
getDatafunction <- function(){
    datapath = "D:\\example"
    files <- dir(datapath)

    for (i in 1:length(files)) {
         assign(paste("data",i, sep="_"), read.csv(paste(datapath,files[i], sep="\\"), header=FALSE))
    }

    return(data)
}
```